# Не изменяются пиксели в Bitmap с PixelFormat "Format8bppIndexed" через unsafe код

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, emgucv, unsafe

изучаю работу с emgu cv в visual c#, возникла проблема при работе с пикселями через unsafe код, в часности изменением Bitmap.Следующий код предназначен для для "попиксельного" закрашивания изображения с PixelFormat "Format32bppArgb" в черный цвет, и он работает.

```
    public unsafe void MyFunc(Mat image)
    {

        //CvInvoke.CvtColor(image, image, ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray);

        Bitmap bitmap = image.Bitmap;

        System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bitmap.PixelFormat);

        byte* scan0 = (byte*)bitmapData.Scan0.ToPointer();

        //byte Bpp = 8; //Format8bppIndexed
        byte Bpp = 32; //Format32bppArgb


        for (int i = 0; i < bitmapData.Height; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < bitmapData.Width; ++j)
            {
                byte* data = scan0 + i * bitmapData.Stride + j * Bpp / 8;

                *data++ = 0;

                *data++ = 0;

                *data = 0;
            }
        }

        bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
    }
```

результат:
[image]
А этот код предназначен для для "попиксельного" закрашивания изображения с PixelFormat "Format8bppIndexed" в черный цвет, и он не работает, создается впечатление что в случае с "Format8bppIndexed" для хранения пикселей изображения используется другое "хранилище" и изменения Bitmap никак не влияют на него.

```
    public unsafe void MyFunc(Mat image)
    {

        CvInvoke.CvtColor(image, image, ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray);

        Bitmap bitmap = image.Bitmap;

        System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bitmap.PixelFormat);

        byte* scan0 = (byte*)bitmapData.Scan0.ToPointer();

        byte Bpp = 8; //Format8bppIndexed
        //byte Bpp = 32; //Format32bppArgb


        for (int i = 0; i < bitmapData.Height; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < bitmapData.Width; ++j)
            {
                byte* data = scan0 + i * bitmapData.Stride + j * Bpp / 8;

                //*data++ = 0;

                //*data++ = 0;

                *data = 0;
            }
        }

        bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
    }
```

результат:
[image]
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я могу делать не так.

...Новости с фронта))

```
        unsafe
        {
            CvInvoke.CvtColor(image, image, ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray);
            Bitmap bitmap = image.Bitmap;
            System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bitmap.PixelFormat);
            byte* scan0 = (byte*)bitmapData.Scan0.ToPointer();
            byte Bpp = 8; //Format8bppIndexed
            //byte Bpp = 32; //Format32bppArgb
            for (int i = 0; i < bitmapData.Height; ++i)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < bitmapData.Width; ++j)
                {
                    byte* data = scan0 + i * bitmapData.Stride + j * Bpp / 8;
                    //*data++ = 0;
                    //*data++ = 0;
                    *data = 0;
                }
            }
            bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
            //////////////////////TEST///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            Bitmap bitmap_test = image.Bitmap;

            bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bitmap.PixelFormat);
            System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bitmapData_test = bitmap_test.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap_test.Width, bitmap_test.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bitmap_test.PixelFormat);

            byte* scan0_test = (byte*)bitmapData_test.Scan0.ToPointer();

            byte[] arr = new byte[bitmap.Width* bitmap.Height];
            byte[] arr_test = new byte[bitmap_test.Width*bitmap_test.Height];

            for (int i = 0; i < bitmapData.Height; ++i)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < bitmapData.Width; ++j)
                {
                    arr[i * bitmapData.Width + j] = scan0[i * bitmapData.Width + j];
                    arr_test[i * bitmapData.Width + j] = scan0_test[i * bitmapData.Width + j];
                }
            }
            bitmap_test.UnlockBits(bitmapData_test);
            bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        }
```

использовав вышеупомянутый код удалось выяснить что изначально взятый "bitmap" успешно претерпел все необходимые изменения, однако повторное взятие свойства image.Bitmap вернуло новый объект, я прихожу к выводу что при PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed объект Mat возвращает не Bitmap а что то вроде Bitmap.Clone(). Я прав?(хочу чтоб нет)

Мне нужен максимально быстрый способ "попиксельного" изменения изображения Mat Format8bppIndexed, "ускоренный" аналог SetPixel. Буду благодарен если кто то подскажет направление в котором копать?

Comment: абсолютно верное впечатление: индексированный [формат](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat?view=netcore-2.1) цвета значит что используется таблица цветов (палитра) -- пиксель содержит не сам цвет, а его индекс в таблице.

Comment: возможно вам пригодится ответ с англ. SO:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593212/editing-8bpp-indexed-bitmaps

Comment: Добрый день, про Palette знаю, в  таком случае код все равно должен был работать так как  при *data = 0 значение должно было ссылаться на Palette[0]